# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed in from a xml table

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to return the currency conversion rate from a website (http://www.floatrates.com/currency/inr/) generated xml table, but the code returns the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

My code is :

```vb
    Sub Trial()
        curr = Application.Index(Range("Currency_Conv[[1 inr ]]"), Application.Match(Range("Convert_to_Currency"), Range("Currency_Conv[Code]"), 0))
        MsgBox (curr)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

That error occurs when the input argument of the Range method is not a valid name or address. One more of your ranges is not able to find an object based on the input you gave it.

In my version of excel, ranges cannot be named `"Currency_Conv[[1 inr ]]"` because it does not allow spaces or brackets in the name.

If you are attempting to navigate an XML file with VBA, it might be better to use an MSXML Object like [DOMDocument60](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/xml/microsoft-xml.htm). This object can read and navigate through XML documents by node names or XPath and can be used to quickly retrieve the desired node or list.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa468547(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is a great link to learn more about getting started with DOMDocument60.